# How to list all the indexes along with their type (BTREE, BRIN, HASH etc...)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, system-tables, catalogs

I'm querying to the system catalog in Postgresql 9.6.4

Getting a result set of tables and their indexes is straight forward,what I'm missing is the index type (BTREE, BRIN, etc..) I can't seem to find the type of index anywhere in the system catalogs.

How can I query the catalogs to get a list of indexes along with their type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The types of indexes in Postgresql are stored in the [`pg_am` catalog table.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-am.html) So to get a list of all tables and their indexes with the index type (or access method ("am") as PostgreSQL calls it) you can run the following

```
SELECT tab.relname, cls.relname, am.amname
FROM pg_index idx 
JOIN pg_class cls ON cls.oid=idx.indexrelid
JOIN pg_class tab ON tab.oid=idx.indrelid
JOIN pg_am am ON am.oid=cls.relam;
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple

Just use the [*System Catalog Information Function*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) **`pg_get_indexdef(index oid)`**:

> Reconstructs the creating command for an index. (This is a decompiled reconstruction, not the original text of the command.)

So just:

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) AS index_definition
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_index;
                                                                                                                                                                              index_definition                                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pg_foreign_data_wrapper_oid_index ON pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper USING btree (oid)
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pg_foreign_server_oid_index ON pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server USING btree (oid)
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pg_user_mapping_oid_index ON pg_catalog.pg_user_mapping USING btree (oid)
...
```

This includes the index ***method*** (what you are asking for). [The manual for Postgres 14:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html)

> ***method***
>
> The name of the index method to be used. Choices are `btree`, `hash`,
> `gist`, `spgist`, `gin`, and `brin`. The default method is `btree`.

... as well as: *operator class* (only if not default), *collation* (only if not default), *schema* (table is always schema-qualified), *table*, and *index* name.

Everything you might possibly need. Maybe even more than that, because the simple query above includes the many indexes of system catalogs.

#### Only indexes from user-land

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid) AS index_definition
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind = 'i';

                                                                                       index_definition                                                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX b2_pkey ON public.b2 USING btree (big_id)
 CREATE INDEX big_big_fts_gin_idx ON public.big USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, big))
 ...
```

The filter `AND c.relkind = 'i'` is redundant, but makes the query faster.

(Related queries typically also add `AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'`. But since there are no *indexes* in `information_schema`, we can skip that.)

#### Deluxe version

You may want data in dedicated columns and a meaningful order on top:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema
     , i.indrelid::regclass::text AS table
     , c.relname AS index
     , a.amname AS index_method
     , opc.operator_classes
     , pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid) AS index_definition
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_index     i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_am        a ON a.oid = c.relam
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (SELECT opc.opcname
                 FROM   unnest(i.indclass::oid[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(oid, ord)
                 JOIN   pg_opclass opc ON opc.oid = o.oid
                 ORDER  BY o.ord)
   ) opc(operator_classes)
WHERE  n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
AND    c.relkind = 'i'
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3, 4;

 schema |       table       |             index             | index_method |          operator_classes           |                                                                                       index_definition                                                                                        
--------+-------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public | b2                | b2_pkey                       | btree        | {int4_ops}                          | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX b2_pkey ON public.b2 USING btree (big_id)
 public | big               | big_big_fts_gin_idx           | gin          | {tsvector_ops}                      | CREATE INDEX big_big_fts_gin_idx ON public.big USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, big))
...
```

Fetching the index method from the catalog table [`pg_am`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-am.html), and operator classes from [`pg_opclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-opclass.html). You might add collations ...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2804452f1202f0f546f6056b54b20ce8)*

Comment: Did OP ask for index definitions?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the schema in case it's needed .

```
SELECT n.nspname, tab.relname, cls.relname, am.amname
FROM pg_index idx 
JOIN pg_class cls ON cls.oid=idx.indexrelid
JOIN pg_class tab ON tab.oid=idx.indrelid
JOIN pg_am am ON am.oid=cls.relam
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = cls.relnamespace
```

Have extended maxTrialfire solution, thank you maxTrialfire!

Comment: The solution you extended is from maxTrialfire (Evan just copyedited). I added some more on the topic.

Comment: Thank you Erwin !